# asp.net (mvc) and mysql, what am I getting in to here?

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I'm building asp.net mvc app, and I want to know the ramifications of me switching from sqlserver2008 to mysql?

Apart from some syntax tweaks, what other things should I am taking into consideration (technically speaking ofcourse) if I want to move over to use mysql?

1. convert sprocs to inline queries
2. transaction and locking maybe handled differently

others?

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences with how the two treat some kinds of locking and concurrency, etc. but for 95% of web applications those kinds of issues simply never come into play. If you're doing standard CRUD, maybe some transactions, executing a few stored procedures? No difference to speak of except the syntax, a good reference to which can be [found here](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/).

I really recommend checking out [DbLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/), which is based on LINQ to SQL but supports lots of different SQL databases. It gets us much closer to making applications truly db-agnostic - you can swap out the SQL Server provider for MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, Firebird, SQLite, Ingres - and all the LINQ expressions stay exactly the same. No need to tweak any queries.

Comment: nice link, so the benefits that nhibernate give you but staying with linq.